# No query results-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have db in which fields which i need to mention here is start date and end date.

In php file i am taking todays date with the code.

```
$today=date("Y-m-d");//2014-02-06
```

I am considering 1 row of table where,
start date is  2014-02-11  and

end date is 2014-02-27

my sql query is below

```
SELECT * FROM `listing_offer` WHERE '2014-02-06' BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date'
```

but it returning all times no rows .!!
did  any 1 have face this problem.
and also guide me if there is syntax error

Comment: remove single quotes arround your column name

Comment: Because 6th of February is not between 11th and 27th? (also remove the quotes from `start_date` and `end_date`, @MKhalidJunaid is correct to spot that, too)

Comment: 2014-02-06 is not between 2014-02-11 and 2014-02-27, thats why no rows are returned

Comment: @Mikpa - that's true, but that's not why no rows are returned. However, once the typos are fixed that WILL BE why no rows are returned!

Comment: thanks guys it worked 
but how to get value in double quote 
 SELECT `listing_offer` . *
FROM `listing_offer`
WHERE id !=0
AND 2014-02-28
BETWEEN start_date
AND end_date
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30 
it is returning result zero due to date is not in double quote
ie. 2014-02-28 pls reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $today=date("Y-m-d");

 $valtoday='\''.$today.'\'';
```

sql query would be

```
select * from table where $valtoday BETWEEN start_date and end_date;
```

//valtoday getting value with quotes to be used in select statement of sql.

Answer (score 1):

Use
SELECT * FROM `listing_offer` WHERE 'start_date'>='2014-02-06' AND 'end_date'<='2014-02-06'